# Flutter IconButton Remove Padding on Left to Align with Title Texts

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

[image: I want to achieve the layout in the attached photo in Flutter. To remove the padding on one side of an Icon Button to align it with title texts above it like title and sub-title texts.]

So far it just goes in the middle even with a padding Edge Inset set to zero and Box Constraints.

```
 Row(children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                      3, 3, 3, 6),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 30,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "Title Sub-title",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        maxLines: 2,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          height: 1.2,
                          fontFamily:
                              'Roboto’,
                          fontSize: 12,
                          letterSpacing: 0.15,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment:
                  MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                      0, 10, 0, 3),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.bookmark_border,
                    size: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Author",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1.1,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
                    fontSize: 8,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: You should try with `crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start` under row, by default it's center

Comment: hi @Jahidul, I tried that and removed the height setting under Text Style as well. But the padding on the left side of the Icon Button did not get less/removed. The only thing that move was the "Author" text line and it became higher and more misaligned with the bookmark icon.

Comment: wrap the row in Padding() and remove the child Padding from the Row

Comment: also, post your code as text - posting as an image makes it hard for us to copy to test and edit

Comment: hello @Ranvir, I tried post the code as text but it keeps getting flagged as having too much code text. :( Can you see the edits part of the question? The code is there.

Comment: do you want to achieve like given image

Comment: @Jahidul. Yes that is what I want to achieve. The bookmark Icon Button be left aligned with the Title and subtitle text above it. Right now, the "Author" text became close to the Icon Button, so I think the padding in the ride side of the icon got reduced. I don't know why the left side won't align even if reduced to zero padding.

Comment: Did my answer working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with column tree and adjust your padding as you desire

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:so_test/screen/child_page.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool visible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Test obviously"),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 3, 0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "Title",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        maxLines: 2,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          height: 1.2,
                          fontSize: 12,
                          letterSpacing: 0.15,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 3, 0),
                  width: 150,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Sub Title",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        height: 1.2,
                        fontSize: 12,
                        letterSpacing: 0.15,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.bookmark_border,
                        size: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Author",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        height: 1.1,
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
                        fontSize: 8,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was able to use it with some modification because of sizing. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the first Container in different column and create the separate column for below three children's.